# Function to load images doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, image, function

Thanks in advance. Be a  newcomer, I have some trouble. I've looked around,But cant find a way.

I write a function about img-loading,if I used it direct,it works well.(Parameter 0)

but if i put it in another funtion , It does't work anyway.(Parameter 1)

```
        function loadpic(t) {
            aImg[t].onload = function () {
            var oimg = document.createElement('img');
            oimg.src = aImg[t].src;
            aList[t].appendChild(oimg);
        }
        function change(){
        loadpic(1);//not work
        }
      loadpic(0);//work well
      change();//not work
```

So,I want to know the reason.And what can I do ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a function that only exists to call another function?  Just call `loadpic(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If it works with a 0 and not 1 this means that your array aImg has one element. Please include the lines where you define aImg, aList and others...

Comment: Thanks a million. It  has been solved . there was something wrong with the aImg and I didn't understand the 'onloading'.